# CLI Go Config.toml file location

Tags: go, command-line-interface, toml

I am attempting to test a Golang application `hauser` locally on via -bash CLI before deploying on a VM.

Per the [documentation](https://github.com/fullstorydev/hauser), I compiled locally and copied the example-config.toml file. I then mapped to the GOPATH and opened hauser.exe to open config.toml file. However, when I execute, it returns `open config.toml: no such file or directory`

```
C02Z30ANLVDV:~ pmcgin2$ $GOPATH/bin/hauser -c Documents/go/bin/config.toml
2020/08/14 18:05:23 Cannot find folder , make sure it exists
C02Z30ANLVDV:~ pmcgin2$ open Documents/go/bin/config.toml
No application knows how to open /Users/pmcgin2/Documents/go/bin/config.toml.
```

Is there an alternative command I can execute to override the default config.toml location for an application like this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities to solve your issue:

- give an absolute path as argument:

```
$GOPATH/bin/hauser -c /Users/pmcgin2/Documents/go/bin/config.toml
```

- give a relative path from the binary location:

```
$GOPATH/bin/hauser -c config.toml
```

Generally, it is easier to use absolute paths.

Comment: I tried absolute path and it returned 'Cannot find file folder, make sure it exists'. Relative path option returned 'open config.toml: no such file or directory'

Comment: Does `/Users/pmcgin2/Documents/go/bin/config.toml` exist!? If `ls /Users/pmcgin2/Documents/go/bin/config.toml` returns an error it doesn't exist.